# Observer stops receiving live data updates when Fragment resumed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

- I have a `ViewModel` that refreshes `myLiveData` every few seconds.
- I have a `MainActivity` that displays a `MyFragment` that observes `myLiveData`

```kotlin
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by activityViewModels()
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        viewModel.myLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            //live data updated
        })
    }
    someButton.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

Once the button is clicked, `SecondActivity` is started.  Once `SecondActivity` is finished, `MainActivity` and `MyFragment` are resumed.

Suddenly, the `myLiveData` `Observer` is found dead in its apartment. My `ViewModel` is still continuously updating `myLiveData`, but now the `Observer`, despite still being registered, is **never notified of another change again**.

- I've tried removing, then re-registering a named `Observer` - doesn't work.
- I've tried changing the lifecycle owner from `viewLifecycleOwner` to `requireActivity()` - doesn't work
- I've tried changing the view model factory provider from `by activityViewModels()` to `by viewModels()` - doesn't work

Something in the Android *lifecycle of death* is causing my `Observer` to both stay registered AND never receive notifications - rendering the `Observer` completely useless - but only when `MyFragment` is resumed.

The ONLY method I've found that works is to `finish()` the current `MainActivity` before starting `SecondActivity`. This ensures that when returning to `MainActivity` (and `MyFragment`), the `Observer` is re-registered from scratch. This is clearly not ideal.

If even manually removing, then re-registering `Observer` doesn't work, what else can be done?

Comment: `MainActivity.finish()` should not work. How are you going back to MainActivity?